# How to read an HTML table like a battleship game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have this HTML table

[image]

And I would like to read it line by line using JavaScript (unfortunately I don't have a `class` or other stuff I can refer to in the table, it's just a plain HTML table) in order to create a map like

```
AC000(red)(green) => cell match.
```

So like in the screenshot the first items in the map will be.

```
AC000AA => AV
AC000AB => AV
...
AC000CA => PC
```

I've tried, using jQuery in node.:

```js
var data = [];
var firstGroup;
const number = '000';
var secondGroup;
$('table').each(function(index) {
  // 5th table...
  if (index == 4) {
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(index) {
      if (index == 1) {
        // firstGroup = $(this).find('td').first().find('b').text();
        firstGroup = $(this).find('td').first().text();
      }
      if (index > 1) {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
          // this is the single cell of the table
          if (index == 0) {
            secondGroup = $(this).text();
          }
          if (index > 0) {
            //data.push($(this).html());
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And it kinda works, but I wonder if there's the fastest way to read it. I don't care about the library or the language, but I would prefer something I can store in an array/map.

Comment: Operate on the backing matrix and refresh the UI afterwards... Manipulate only the 2D array... You can always calculate the (x, y) position of the clicked cell.

Comment: Use the [Table API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the matrix after clicking on a cell in the table. After you capture the event, set the value of the cell and refresh the table.

If you want, you can either refresh just the cell you clicked, or the entire table (to ensure is is synchronized with the matrix).

```js
const DEBUG = false;

var data = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

/* jQuery plugins for accessing a table */
(($) => {
  $.matrixToTable = function(matrix, $target) {
    return ($target || $('<table>')).empty().append(matrix.map(row => {
      return $('<tr>').append(row.map(col => {
        return $('<td>').text(col);
      }));
    }));
  };
  $.fn.getCell = function(x, y) {
    return this.find(`tr:nth-child(${y + 1}) td:nth-child(${x + 1})`);
  };
  $.fn.setCell = function(x, y, value) {
    return this.getCell(x, y).text(value);
  };
  $.fn.cellPosition = function() {
    let $td    = $(this),
        $tr    = $td.closest('tr'),
        $table = $tr.closest('table');
    return {
      x : $tr.children().index($td),
      y : $table.children().index($tr)
    };
  };
  $.fn.populateCells = function(matrix) {
    this.find('tr').each((row, tr) => {
      $(tr).find('td').each((col, td) => {
        $(td).text(matrix[col][row]);
      });
    });
    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);

$('body').append($.matrixToTable(data, $('.board')));

$('.board td').on('click', function(e) {
  let pos = $(this).cellPosition();
  if (data[pos.x][pos.y] === 'X') {
    console.log(`Cell (${pos.x + 1}, ${pos.y + 1}) is already selected!`);
  } else {
    data[pos.x][pos.y] = 'X'; // Update the value in the matrix
    if (DEBUG) {
      updateTable($(this).closest('table'));
    } else {
      updateTable($(this).closest('table'), Object.assign(pos, {
        val : data[pos.x][pos.y]
      }));
    }
  }
});

// Update the table, according to the matrix's current state.
function updateTable($table, pos) {
  // If you passed in positional info (optional), only update that cell...
  if (arguments.length > 1 && pos != null) {
    $table.setCell(pos.x, pos.y, pos.val);
  } else {
    $table.populateCells(data);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace;
}
table, td {
  border: thin solid black;
}
td {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
td:hover {
  background: #FFD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="board"></table>
```

---

Borrowing trincot's example, this is the way to do it if you want to see a pure jQuery implementation.

***Note:** It looks a bit more involved, but safely checks if there is a `thead`/`tbody` present.*

```js
(($) => {
  $.fn.reduce = function(callback, initial) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(this, callback, initial);
  };
  $.fn.every = function(callback) {
    return Array.prototype.every.call(this, callback);
  };
  $.fn.allEqual = function() {
    return this.every((e, i, a) => i > 0 ? JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(a[i-1]) : true);
  };
  $.fn.readData = function(prefixDelim) {
    let includesHeader = this.find('thead').length > 0;
    let rows = this.find('tbody tr');
    let header = includesHeader ? this.find('thead > tr') : rows.first();
    let prefix = header.find('td').first().text() + prefixDelim;
    return rows.filter(i => i > 0 || includesHeader).reduce((obj, row) => {
      return $(row).find('td').slice(1).reduce((obj1, cell, col) => {
        let rowPrefix = $(row).find('td').first().text();
        let colPrefix = $(header.find('td').slice(1).get(col)).text();
        return $.extend(obj1, {
          [prefix + rowPrefix + colPrefix] : $(cell).text()
        });
      }, obj);
    }, {});
  }
})(jQuery);

// Both tables are the same...
console.log($('table').map((i, table) => $(table).readData('000')).allEqual());
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Arial; }
td { text-align: center; border: 2px solid grey; padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; }
thead tr td, tr td:first-child { background: #ff8; font-weight: bold; }
thead tr td { color: green; }
thead tr:first-child > td:first-child { color: black; }
tbody tr td:first-child { color: red; }

table.no-header tr:first-child > td, td:first-child { background: #ff8; font-weight: bold  }
table.no-header tr:first-child > td { color: green }
table.no-header td:first-child { color: red }
table.no-header tr:first-child>td:first-child { color: black }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="no-header">
<tr><td>AC</td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td><td>J</td><td>K</td><td>L</td><td>M</td><td>N</td><td>P</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>CN</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td></tr>
<tr><td>E</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td></tr>
</table>
<hr />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>AC</td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td><td>J</td><td>K</td><td>L</td><td>M</td><td>N</td><td>P</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>CN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td></tr>
    <tr><td>D</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that needs a table element and a format string as argument. The format string could in this case be "AC000{row}{col}". The {row} part will be replaced with the value found in the first column, and the {col} part will be replaced with what is found in the first row.

The function will return a plain object, where the key is the cell address (according to the format), and the value is the text content found in that cell:

```js
function getTableLookup(table, format) {
    let headers = Array.from(table.rows[0].cells, cell => cell.textContent).slice(1);
    return Object.fromEntries(Array.from(table.rows).slice(1).flatMap(({cells}) => {
        let formaty = format.replace('{row}', cells[0].textContent);
        return headers.map((label, x) =>
            [formaty.replace('{col}', label), cells[x+1].textContent]
        )
    }));
}

let lookup = getTableLookup(document.querySelector("table"), "AC000{row}{col}");
console.log(lookup);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Arial }
td {text-align: center; border: 2px solid grey; padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; }
tr:first-child>td, td:first-child { background: #ff8; font-weight: bold  }
tr:first-child>td { color: green }
td:first-child { color: red }
tr:first-child>td:first-child { color: black }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>AC</td><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td><td>J</td><td>K</td><td>L</td><td>M</td><td>N</td><td>P</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>AV</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td><td>CN</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PC</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>PV</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td><td>BL</td></tr>
<tr><td>E</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td><td>BO</td></tr>
</table>
```